# How Reset Jquery Animation in Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the button the page goes up but I want the button going to back. How can I do that?

```
$("#toUp").click(function(){
    $("html,body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: "0" }, 1000);
    $(this).animate({bottom:"auto",top:"0"},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#toUp").css({top:"auto",bottom:"10"});
    }, 1000);
});
```

Codepen : [My Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/Modal/pen/jObEEGW)

Comment: Note: works in the first but does not work in the others

Answer (score 1):

In the end of the animation, it adds `top: 0` to the `#toUp` element.
So, consider adding 100ms to the setTimeout method (i.e. 1100ms).

```
$("#toUp").click(function(){
  $("html,body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: "0" }, 1000);
  $(this).animate({bottom:"auto",top:"0"},1000);
  setTimeout(function(){   
    $("#toUp").css({top:"auto",bottom:"10"});
  }, 1100);
});
```